# Adding price and total column in shipping invoice in opencart

Tags: php, opencart2.x

Opencart by default doesn't show price and total in the print shipping at the admin side.
So I added two more columns to the table in shipping invoice in order_shipping.tpl in admin/view/template/sale/order_shipping.tpl
but I got the error as

**Notice: Undefined variable: column_price in /home/blossewp/public_html/admin/view/template/sale/order_shipping.tpl on line 69**
**Notice: Undefined index: price in /home/blossewp/public_html/admin/view/template/sale/order_shipping.tpl on line 81**

[image]

To me it seems the value is coming from the same controller order.php, I can't guess why then these variables are not visible inside order_shipping.tpl if they are visible in /home/blossewp/public_html/admin/view/template/sale/order_invoice.tpl.

Please help. The shipping invoice must have the price and total column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is very clear

> Notice: Undefined variable: **column_price** in /home/blossewp/public_html/admin/view/template/sale/order_shipping.tpl on line 69 Notice: Undefined index: **price** in /home/blossewp/public_html/admin/view/template/sale/order_shipping.tpl on line 81

It means that these variables are not defined, hence they are not passed from the controller to the view, the appropriate controller is located in `<OC_ROOT>/admin/controller/sale/order.php` , `class ControllerSaleOrder` @ `function shipping()` and I don't see your entries defined there

To solve the problem, just define them:
**(1)** Find `$data['column_... = $this->language->get(...` and add after `$data['column_price'] = $this->language->get('column_price');`
**(2)** Find `$product_data[] = array(` and add an entry `'price' => $product_info['price'],` or `$this->currency->format($product_info['price'])` if you want to format it!

Comment: Thanks I added it and it worked. Also I added totals column. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

admin/controller/sale/order.php
find :

```
public function shipping() {
```

and before

```
$data['orders'][] = array(
```

add

```
        $total_data = array();

    $totals = $this->model_sale_order->getOrderTotals($order_id);

    foreach ($totals as $total) {
        $total_data[] = array(
            'title' => $total['title'],
            'text'  => $this->currency->format($total['value'], $order_info['currency_code'], $order_info['currency_value'])
        );
    }
```

Then after

```
$data['orders'][] = array(
```

add

```
'total'            => $total_data,
```

Next step, open admin/view/template/sale/order_shipping and add

```
{% set last_total = order.total|last %}{{ last_total.text }}
```